# Style for every state of an a tag?

Tags: css

Is there a way of specifying `a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active` and maybe also `a:focus` in one go using css?

Comment: You mean like `a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {}`?

Comment: What do you mean, "...in one go"?  You want all `a:*` to be the same style?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to style *all* anchors; not just anchors used as links, but named anchors as well (i.e. `<a name="foo"></a>`) simply use the following css selector:

```
a
```

That's it.

If you *don't* want named anchors, but instead want to style only links that have an `[href]` attribute, you should use the comma-separated list of selectors:

```
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

If you're running into specificity issues, you'll need to post some HTML code and review [CSS specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: Easily remembered with this handy mnemonic: 

_Lord Vader's Handle Formerly Anakin_

Answer (score 0):

Just name them all at once and specify the style:

```
a:link, a:active, a:visited, a:hover, a:focus
{
}
```

Comment: Hahaa... was wondering if someone actually would post this as an answer!

Comment: I couldn't think what else he would mean?, and the comment wasn't there when I wrote the answer!

Comment: I know, I'm pretty sure you thought right. But even though two people ninja'd you in comments you'll get the rep.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a single style for all states, you can simply do this:

```css
a{
  color: green;
}
```